# c# Regular expression to capture word after a captured group

Tags: c#, regex

I have item numbers in the general form: 1-3 digits followed by optional lower case character followed by optional single digit followed by a word followed by optional single digit. 
For example, all of the following are legitimate item numbers: `"21aRepair", "04iMod2", "04d1RR", "5", "07", "8a", "09b", "04g3"`

I need to break these item numbers up into components of the form: 
Component 1) 1-3 digits followed by optional lower case character followed by optional single digit 
Component 2) a word 
Component 3) optional single digit

For example:

`"21aRepair"` should become `"21a", "Repair", null`

`"04iMod2"` should become `"04i", "Mod", "2"`

`"04d1RR"` should become `"04d1", "RR", null`

`"5"` should become `"5", null, null`

I have the following `regex: (^\d{1,3}[a-z]?\d?)` that works fine for component 1. I have tried several options for component 2 without success.

I thought the following: `(?<=^\d{1,3}[a-z]?\d?)([a-zA-Z]*\d?)` would work. Adding the lookbehind `"(?<="` to the component 1 pattern should say "take whatever is after component 1", and the group `([a-zA-Z]*\d?)` should match components 2 and 3. This does not yield the expected results.  Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: The first character of the word in the middle is always in uppercase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using

```
^(\d{1,3}[a-z]?\d?)([a-zA-Z]*)(\d?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7BXC67/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{1,3}[a-z]?\d?)` - Group 1: component, 1 to 3 digits, an optional lowercase ASCII letter and an optional digit
- `([a-zA-Z]*)` - Group 2: word, zero or more ASCII letters
- `(\d?)` - Group 3: an optional digit
- `$` - end of string

In C#, use

```
var m = Regex.Match(str, @"^(\d{1,3}[a-z]?\d?)([a-zA-Z]*)(\d?)$");
```

check if `m.Success` is *true*, and access the three groups using `m.Groups[n].Value` where `n` is the group ID.

Comment: =) Identical to what I had

Comment: There can be variations depending on what the "word" can be.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!